# Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Tags: apache-kafka, hortonworks-data-platform, producer

I have installed Kafka and doing some basic testing. I am able to create topics using scripts provided under Kafka-broker/bin folder.

But when I am trying to produce message getting below WARNing every time I run this. And no message is getting generated. Please advice.

```
[root@node2 bin]# ./kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test_master
>testmsg1
    [2019-05-15 06:25:19,092] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
    [2019-05-15 06:25:19,197] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
    [2019-05-15 06:25:19,349] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
    [2019-05-15 06:25:19,562] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
    [2019-05-15 06:25:20,017] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
    [2019-05-15 06:25:20,876] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
    [2019-05-15 06:25:21,987] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
    [2019-05-15 06:25:22,957] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
    [2019-05-15 06:25:23,818] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
    ^Corg.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Producer closed while send in progress
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:826)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:803)
            at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.send(ConsoleProducer.scala:75)
            at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.main(ConsoleProducer.scala:57)
            at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer.main(ConsoleProducer.scala)
    Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Requested metadata update after close
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata.awaitUpdate(Metadata.java:188)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.waitOnMetadata(KafkaProducer.java:938)
            at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:823)
            ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 4):

Open `Server.xml` of each broker of your cluster and make following changes

Change the `listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092` to `listeners=PLAINTEXT://<our ip address>:9092`

Answer (score 0):

Just remove your local host and write the port

EXAMPLE:

{--broker-list **172.0.0.1:9092**}   will be changed to     { --broker-list **:9092** }